# Factors R not fun: pulling labels vs levels

Tags: r, class, label

I'm loading a csv file that contains colleges and their conferences into R. When I read the file and create a data frame, it automatically makes the conferences class factor. All I want is to pull the conference but I can only pull the "levels" being random numbers. When I use as.character it stores the random numbers. Can anyone assist me with this?

the following issue has taken me so long to make zero progress so I'd greatly appreciate guidance / assistance.

```
> data <- read.csv("Regression Data Working File.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# the file is essentially just a list of colleges in one column and their corresponding conference in the other column
> class(data$conference) # is a vector of college conferences (SEC, ACC, etc.)
[1] "character"
> data$conference[2]
[1] "7" # should be "ACC" and it is "ACC" when I use View(data)
```

Comment: Please provide your code with a sample data, what you've got and wht you expect

Comment: have you tried `data$conference`

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you don't want it to be a factor? So `read.csv("something.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)`?

Comment: (a) factor levels are never random numbers; (b) specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `readcsv` call; (c) please post some sample data and code so we can see if you are doing something else wrong

Comment: what you've posted now is really surprising/weird; we need a reproducible example. Can you post a sample file somewhere? Can you show us the results of `str(data)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I did to fix this. My original file had the column of conferences populated using a vlookup but I made sure to copy and paste these results as values (not knowing if the vlookup function instead of the data would impact the data in the csv file / r). In response to the comment above to provide a sample data file, I copied and pasted the values into a new excel file and tried that data in r and it worked. So I went back to my previous data file and deleted the vlookup data array in a different sheet to try to find an explanation and that resolved the issue. So my guess is that something about the conversion from an excel file into a csv file used the data array that was used for the vlookup and stored the values as that. Thanks for your help in troubleshooting this! Have a great weekend
Thanks,
OP